# want to remove textview on top of screen

Tags: android

How to remove textview right under status bar?. Its used to display app name by default. Even I delete main.xml, it does not work.  I want move up widgets after removing textview.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The textview you are talking about is knowing as **Title bar** of the application, which is mostly used to display title of current activity.

**Programmatically:**

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

 //Remove status bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**Design time: just make changes inside the AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the title bar of your app. Add this to your manifest file in application tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```